# Android Font Deleted/Not Working

Tags: root-access, system, fonts

I was trying to change the font for BENGALI language in my phone. **I have my phone rooted.**

[image]

Copied these six fonts to someplace else and then Deleted these six fonts from **system/fonts**. I could not install my intended font. So, wanted to revert back to the originals.

When I copied the original fonts back, and restarted the phone, the BENGALI fonts are still not working. What to do??

I am using Derpfest rom on **Android 10.**

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The permission bits for the font files should be rw-r--r-- . When you copy some file from someplace else to any system folder , check for this pattern in the permission bits and make necessary corrections to do that. It should work.